# best practice: reportservers and sql servers

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

we have three SQL servers serving a variety of applications on different webservers.
Each application is using reporting services functionality.
The average load per server per month is about 40.000 reports, taking an average of 3.1 secs to deliver a report.

At this moment the the situation is as follows:

- Application A has his database on SQLServer A and is using Reporting
  Services on SQLServer A. (SQL 2008)
- Application B has his database on    SQLServer B and is using
  Reporting Services on SQLServer B. (SQL 2008R2)
- Application C has his database on SQLServer C and is using
  Reporting Services on SQLServer C.  (SQL 2008R2).

We have just bought a new server, runnning SQL 2012.
Would it be wise to move all reporting to the Reporting Server 2012?
My idea is that there would be a significant performance-gain. Also, There would be only one reporting server to manage. But is that so? Are there penalties when running reports on one server while the database feeding the reports is on another server? Is it a problem if the Reporting Services version is different then that of the database server?

I would like very much to hear your thoughts on this.
Performance and manageability are two key-components.

Greetings and thanks for thinking with me,

Henro

Comment: It could be useful to break down the 3.1 secs into the three different stages: data retrieval, processing, and rendering. (Have a peek at [executionlog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Enterprise Edition of SSRS 2012 (so that could take advantage of scale out via deploying parts of the SSRS implementation on different servers)?  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Reporting) a SSRS 2012 feature list by edition.  Also, are you using any scheduled (i.e. snapshot or scheduled delivery) of reports to balance the load requests?

Comment: Lynn, i think we are not. I will do the comparisons.